# Validate that textarea filled and multiselect clicked within form before enabling button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Link to relevant fiddle (current javascript taken from this stackoverflow [**response**](http://www.example.com/)): https://jsfiddle.net/5qomb6fe/.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h5>Input Words and Make Selection</h5>
    <br>
    <form method='post'>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="field" name="words" rows="12"></textarea>
      <br>
      <select class="form-control" id="type" multiple name="type" size="13">
        <option value="">Null</option>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option>
        <option value="Six">Six</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-danger" name="button" type="submit" value="Submit", id="keybutton" disabled="disabled">
    </form>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function() {
  $('form > textarea').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('form > textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('#keybutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#keybutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
})()
```

While this effectively enables the button when the form is filled, I want to know how I can enable the button only after the form is filled **and** a selection within the multiselect has been made.

My knowledge of javascript, jquery, etc. is quite limited. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not tag your question with something that has nothing to do with the question.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this one, or check on snippet. i already updated the snippet, you can select first and type then the `button` is enabled this is vice versa.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/5qomb6fe/5/
```

```js
(function() {
function enabledButton(){
  if(empty == false && selection == false){
       $('#keybutton').removeAttr('disabled');
      }else{
         $('#keybutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
}
var selection = null;
var empty = null;
  $('form > textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('form > textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val()=='') {
         empty = true;
        }else{
         empty = false;
        }
    });
    enabledButton();
  });
  $('.selection').on('change',function(){
      selection = false;
      enabledButton();
  });
})()
```

```css
<style>
      body {
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      }
      th, td {
      padding: 1px;
      }
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <h5>Input Words and Make Selection</h5>
    <br>
    <form method='post'>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="field" name="words" rows="12"></textarea>
      <br>
      <select class="form-control selection" id="type" multiple name="type" size="13">
        <option value="">Null</option>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option>
        <option value="Six">Six</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-danger" name="button" type="submit" value="Submit", id="keybutton" disabled="disabled">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: works like a charm! and if you have multiple select boxes, this seems to work as well: https://jsfiddle.net/mx9s74Lu/1/